# Excel VBA to merge data from multiple rows

Tags: excel, rows, cells, vba

I have a quite big XLS with information spread over multiple rows that looks like:

```
TopName   Name   Mode   Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4
-----------------------------------------------------
Foo       Name1  ModeX  x()
Foo       Name2  ModeY                  x()
Foo       Name1  ModeX                  y() 
Foo       Name1  ModeX                          y()
Foo       Name2  ModeY  y()
```

What I now want to do is merge the data based on the name into a new sheet or Excel file. The output table should look something like

```
Name   Mode   Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4
-------------------------------------------
Name1  ModeX  x()             y()     y()
Name2  ModeY  y()             x()
```

I myself will try to come up with a solution via VBA, but there is surely somebody who is way better in that and can maybe post a simple solution?

Update:
I tried the following but it does not work at all:

```
Sub ConsolidateRows()
'takes rows and consolidate one or many cells, based on one or many cells matching with above or below rows.

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim colMatch As Variant, colConcat As Variant

'**********PARAMETERS TO UPDATE****************
Const strMatch As String = "B"    'columns that need to match for consolidation, separated by commas
Const strConcat As String = "C,D,F,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U"     'columns that need consolidating, separated by commas
Const strSep As String = ", "     'string that will separate the consolidated values
'*************END PARAMETERS*******************

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'disable ScreenUpdating to avoid screen flashes

colMatch = Split(strMatch, ",")
colConcat = Split(strConcat, ",")

lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row

For i = lastRow To 4 Step -1 'loop from last Row to one

    For j = 0 To UBound(colMatch)
        If Cells(i, colMatch(j)) &#x3c;&#x3e; Cells(i - 1, colMatch(j)) Then GoTo nxti
    Next

    For j = 0 To UBound(colConcat)
        Cells(i - 1, colConcat(j)) = Cells(i - 1, colConcat(j)) & strSep & Cells(i, colConcat(j))
    Next

    Rows(i).Delete

nxti:
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'reenable ScreenUpdating
End Sub
```

Update2: OK, the file does not even have two matching values in consecutive rows and thus, the code above can obviously not work :( What I need is some kind of dictionary or something...

Comment: Your question is similar to : http://superuser.com/questions/405555/how-can-i-group-by-and-sum-a-column-in-excel. Hope this may help.Regards,

Comment: There is a syntax error in this line of your macro (conditional operator is missing): If Cells(i, colMatch(j))  Cells(i - 1, colMatch(j))

Comment: Thanks! I updated it. That was due to html tags, so <> was interpreted as an empty tag.

Comment: your posted code (presumably copied from somewhere) is not designed to do what you want

Comment: It did work, though... Just needed to sort by name first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pertinent to your task and sample Excel Worksheet data shown below:

```
TopName Name    Mode    Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4

Foo     Name1   ModeX   x()         
Foo     Name2   ModeY                    x()    
Foo     Name1   ModeX                    y()    
Foo     Name1   ModeX                          y()
Foo     Name2   ModeY   y()
```

you can use the following Excel VBA code snippet:

```
Sub ConsolidateRowsData()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'disable ScreenUpdating

lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row

'concatenate Item data
For i = 3 To lastRow  'outer loop thru data rows (starting w/row 3)
    For j = i + 1 To lastRow 'inner loop thru data rows
        If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(j, 2) Then
            For k = 4 To 7 'loop thru columns: Item1...Item4
                If (Cells(i, k) = "" And Cells(j, k) <> "") Then
                    Cells(i, k) = Cells(j, k)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next

'delete duplicates
For i = 3 To lastRow   'outer loop thru data rows
    For j = lastRow To i + 1 Step -1 'inner loop thru data rows
        If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(j, 2) Then
            Rows(j).Delete
        End If
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'reenable ScreenUpdating
End Sub
```

Even though it's not optimized for speed, but will do the job. Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: Thanks! I am just trying it but as you said, it will take a while ;) Nevertheless, thank you very much for the effort.

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark the answer accepted, and good luck with your project. Best regards,